# How to access another apex class methods from an apex webservice class

Tags: apex, webservices, apexrest

All I have been finding is webservice examples where they query something from salesforce, or insert a basic SObject like a contact or lead or account...

I am wanting to set up an apex webservice class that will access methods from a packaged class, but have not been able to find any examples on how this is done.

Can anyone point me in the right direction on accessing another classes methods from a webservice class? As well as what the urlMapping would need to be for @RestResource tag?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You do this in exactly the same way as you would call another class from any other (non-webservice) class. That is, you create a new instance of your target class, store it in a variable, and then call your method (or `ClassName.staticMethodName()` in the case of static methods).

The webservice keyword is basically just a hint for Salesforce to invoke the automagical process that they use to allow that class to be accessed via http requests.

Comment: Do I put the webservice keyword before the method I want to access? Or in the method of my webservice class that is accessing it?

Comment: @TylerDahle no. _It is literally no different_ from calling `A.methodB()` from inside class `C`. For these types of questions, one of the best things to do is to try playing around with it for yourself in a sandbox. Curiosity and failure are both magnificent teachers, and you'll learn a lot more if you try getting your hands a little dirty before asking for help.